# What is this tool used for and what is it called?

Tags: tools, hand-tools, identify-a-tool

What is this tool called and what is it used for?

I have searched for the product number on Biltema without luck as the number is not visible anymore. Contacting Biltema with the same pictures also gave me no answer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a mechanic's tool, used to install springs on car brakes. For example https://www.jbtools.com/lisle-45100-brake-spring-tool/?wi=off&gclid=CjwKCAjw69moBhBgEiwAUFCx2NsKK5Y10jyz5yuRG6Bx5WNYU9Ty8JEnimMbWVfv_gjqpEbsgjUgYhoC4CwQAvD_BwE

Comment: Or for what might be an exact match: [Laser Tools 2706 Brake Spring Tool](https://www.lasertools.co.uk/Product/2706/Brake-Spring-Tool).